# How to add EditText inside an ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an `ImageView` and I want to add `EditText` inside it where a player can enter his/her score. The box layout is already there but it is on image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I set the background image instead of an `ImageView`. I hope the result is like you expect. it.